# How to set a video caption track as default dynamically

Tags: javascript, html5-video, plyr, caption

I need to set a video caption track as default dynamically, I feel I missing some detail do reach it.

Part of my code is this:

```
track = document.createElement("track");
track.kind = "captions";
track.label = "Português";
track.srclang = "pt";
track.src = "captionsXYZ.vtt";
```

I tried do make that caption as default, doing this:

```
track.setAttribute('default', '');
```

and this

```
track.setAttribute('default', 'default')
```

But it shows up like this on browser:

```
<track label="Ligar" kind="captions" srclang="pt" src="captionsXYZ.vtt" default="">
```

And I need to be like this:

```
<track label="Ligar" kind="captions" srclang="pt" src="captionsXYZ.vtt" default>
```

But why do I need that?

I am working with a video player called [plyr.io](https://plyr.io/) which is very good, mas it need caption is set default to show cc button, otherwise it doesn't show up. I did a manual test with FF inspector, deleting what I do not need it worked beautifully!

So, do you wise people have any clue?

I thank you all in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, friends.

Going a little deeper into plyr.io code I found a setup that solves my problem.

```
const player = new Plyr.setup('video', {
         captions: {
          active: true,
          update:true,// THAT line solved my problem
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`track.setAttribute('default', '');` works for me

Result:
[image]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/NWrMmBx)

Is this what you are trying to achieve or did I read the question wrong? :)

Comment: Hm... yes, yours worked. But mine still doesn't. I will paste prints here to show part of my code.

Comment: Hi :)! I can see that you are using FireFox and they seem to write attributes without values like that. Chrome writes default and Firefox write default=""